# Insert CSS in inApp Browser Ionic- Hide URL and Color of Address bar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I want to Hide URL and change the color of URL bar with Close button, Help me out, Below is my code help me to ADD CSS to inAPPbrowser in Ionic

```js
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
private iab: InAppBrowser
    launch(url) {

        //For Image

        if(url){
          let ext = this.getUrlExtention(url) //To recognize Image or PDF
          console.log("url ext: ", ext);

          if(ext == 'jpg' || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "png")
          this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.iab.create(url, "_self");
          });
          //For PDF
          else if(ext == "pdf" || ext == "docx")
          this.platform.ready().then(() => {
              let pdf = encodeURIComponent(url);
              this.iab.create('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url='+pdf, "_self");
          });
        }
        else{
          console.error("url not found: ", url,"  ");

        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you provide more code please? What is `ext`? `this.iab`?

Comment: I have updated the code
Hope this helps?